# jQuery custom dropdown select box not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button 'button' that activates a dropdown box 'box':

```
$('.button').click(function() 
{           
    $(this).siblings(".box").toggle();
});
```

Everytime the button is clicked the dropdown box hides or shows

```
$('.box').blur(function()
{   
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Now I want to implement a blur, so that when the user clicks something other than the dropdown box, the box hides itself.

**BUT**

Now when I click the button while the dropdown is open, it closes and reopens. I feel like I'm stuck in a Catch-22.

The problem is, is that blur and .click are both firing when I click the button while the dropdown is open.

Comment: the "blur" event is the act of losing focus on an object.. so really i would add something to handle the "click" event of those objects to hide "unhidden" drop downs..

Comment: i have that elsewhere in the code and is not the problem.

Comment: it sounds like you've got circular logic, you're re-showing it after it hides itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using blur, look for a click anywhere on the document, but prevent bubbling up when clicking on the box or the button.

```
$('.button').click( function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('.box').toggle();
});
$('html').click( function() {
  $('.box').hide();
});
$('.box, .button').click( function() {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLdtz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').blur(function()
{  

    if($(this).is(":visible"))    
     $(this).toggle();

});
```

Comment: this does not work. the click function will kick in and see that it is hidden and show it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.box').blur(function(event)
{   
    $(this).hide();
    event.stopPropagation(); //prevent event from bubbling up the DOM
});
```

Comment: I had a typo in `event.stopPropagation()` Try it again.